# Using count in dql-Symfony

Tags: dql

I have created two repository to match payroll week (one week already in database) to payroll period (2 weeks entered by the user). but keep getting error message that says there's no match even when there's a match. The payroll week and payroll period should match exactly.

**Custom Repository**

```
 public function findBystartdateAndenddate($startdate, $enddate)
    {

       $repository=$this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('comtwclagripayrollBundle:Payrollweek');
       //$startdate='startdate';
       //$enddate='enddate';
       $qb=$repository->createQueryBuilder('pw');
       $qb->select('pw');
       $qb->where('pw.startdate=:startdate');
       $qb->Andwhere('pw.enddate=:enddate');
       $qb->setParameter('startdate', $startdate);
       $qb->setParameter('enddate', $enddate);
       $qb->getquery()->getResult();
    }

   public function countBystartdateAndenddate($startdate, $enddate)
    {
      $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('pw');
      $qb->select('count(pw.id)');
      $qb->where('pw.startdate=:startdate');
      $qb->Andwhere('pw.enddate=:enddate');
      $qb->setParameter('startdate', $startdate);
      $qb->setParameter('enddate', $enddate);

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
    }
```

**Controller**

```
 public function createAction(Request $request)
    {



        $entity = new Payrollperiod();

        $form = $this->createCreateForm($entity);

        $form->handleRequest($request);


            if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) { 

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

            $payrollperiod = $em->getRepository('comtwclagripayrollBundle:Payrollperiod')->findOneBy(['startdate'=>$form->get('startDate')->getData(), 'enddate'=>$form->get('endDate')->getData()]);

            $payrollweek = $em->getRepository('comtwclagripayrollBundle:Payrollweek')->findBystartdateAndenddate($entity->getStartDate() , $entity->getEndDate());

            $counter = $em->getRepository('comtwclagripayrollBundle:Payrollweek')->countBystartdateAndenddate($entity->getStartDate() , $entity->getEndDate());


           if($counter){
            //If entity exists
            if ($payrollperiod){
                    $this->addFlash('error', 'Error: A payroll period is already present with the same start and end date.');
                    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('payrollperiod'));
                }
                //If PayrollWeek matches the Payrollperiod entered
               elseif ( $payrollweek){
                foreach ($payrollweek as $pWeek) {
                    $pWeek->setPayrollperiodid($entity); 
                    $em->persist($pWeek);
                }

              $em->persist($entity);
              $em->flush();

                $this->addFlash('success', 'Payroll Period was added.');
                $this->addFlash('success', 'Payroll week was updated.');
                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('payrollperiod'));
               //return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('payrollperiod_show', array('payrollperiodid' => $entity->getpayrollperiodid())));
                 }
                 else{
                   $this->addFlash('error', 'Payroll Period does not match a payroll week.');
                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('payrollperiod'));  
                 }
           }

           //return $this->render('comtwclagripayrollBundle::new.html.twig',array('form' => $form->createView()));
           return array(
               'entity' => $entity,
               'form'   => $form->createView(),
           );   

            }
    }
```

Comment: Can someone answer this question please